# Any suggestions on how to extract number corn seeds in a half cut corn using Image processing or even machine learning?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, contour

I have tried implementing this using OpenCV and followed the below processing steps:

- Converted image to Grayscale
- Apply threshold
- Get Contours and draw them
- Print the number of contours

**My try 1:** I experimented with the threshold values and contour areas, but the system considers the whole corn as a single seed rather than each seed.

**My try 2:** Also experimented with Hue values to highlight yellow colors, but that didn't yield satisfying results.

**Output:**
[image]

**Source Image:**
[image]

```
# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('img2.png')
img = cv2.resize(img,(250,250))

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

# Apply a threshold to the image to obtain a binary image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours in the binary image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Iterate through each contour and count the number of seeds
num_seeds = 0
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > 100 :  # filter out small contours
        num_seeds += 1

# Print the number of seeds found
print("Number of seeds:", num_seeds)

# Display the image with contours drawn on it
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: source image please. that's the most vital part of a [mre]. -- since they're densely packed, you might want to just use AI for this. either object detection or instance segmentation. this will require you to label a few images for training data.

Comment: Okay, any suggestion on which Object detection model is suitable for detecting small objects like seeds?